# "Modernized" OAUTH: callback not triggering

Tags: google-oauth

This is in reference to:

https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

which asks to post questions on stack overflow under #google-oauth.

Two questions from the developer of an email app for Android, trying to implement the "modernized" OAUTH flow as described at the link above.

1 - I registered my callback URI in Google Developer Console, looks like this: `org.kman.AquaMail:/oauth2redirect`

2 - My code builds an approval URI, based on `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`, basically same as it did for WebView, but the `redirect_uri` parameter is the above custom scheme URI.

3 - I am able to bring up this approval URI in a Chrome Custom Tab

4 - Added this to my manifest, copied it out of `AppAuth-Android` sample:

> ```
>   <!-- OAUTH result activity for Gmail -->
>
>   <activity android:name=".mail.oauth.OAuthGmailResultActivity">
>       <intent-filter>
>           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
>
>           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
>           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
>
>           <data android:scheme="org.kman.AquaMail"/>
> ```

( argh, the markdown parser ate the closing tags for intent-filter and activity, but they're there )

So far so good (almost).

Now this turns bad:

When I actually sign in, in the Chrome Custom Tab, and grant the permissions by pressing "allow" on the screen that says "app would like to" --

My "result activity" the one with the intent filter for my custom scheme, does not get invoked.

Instead the Chrome Tab just redirects to google.com (.ru in my case).

There is nothing interesting in the logcat (such as a failed attempt to run this activity).

How do I go about debugging this?

PS - I know the approval_url with the custom scheme is there, I can see it  in the Chrome Tab if I tap the "three dots" and then the "info" icon.

Answer (score 0):

Duh. In case someone else runs into this.

By the time the approval_url makes it back to my app, it's been converted to lowercase.

So `org.kman.AquaMail:/oauth2redirect` becomes `org.kman.aquamail:/oauth2redirect`.

And so the intent filter for the "result activity" needs to have the scheme in lowercase as well.